# Aptana French version

Tags: version, locale, aptana

Is there a French version of Aptana? Or is there a package to install, so one may use the software in French?

Comment: [Here's something](http://ascabe.bakufu.org/aptana/helpg-2.html) I found that might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do either of the following to change the language of your Aptana UI:

1. Change your language of your operating system, or
2. Change your shortcut to Aptana by typing the following on the command line when you start Aptana.

Aptana.exe -fr [2-letter-language-abbreviation]

Reference : [Changing Interface aptana in different language](http://ascabe.bakufu.org/aptana/helpg-2.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, I'll try tonight. I'll keep you posted!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to tell you, but there is no French version of Aptana Studio.
*Désolé de vous le dire, mais il n'ya pas de version française de Aptana Studio*.

Try downloading a version of eclipse and see if there is a French language kit available and use Aptana Studio as a plugin to that configuration.
*Essayez de télécharger une version d'Eclipse et de voir si il ya un kit de langue française et à utiliser Aptana Studio comme un plugin à cette configuration*.

Source: http://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/questions/629-changing-the-aptana-studio-interface-to-a-different-language

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, I'll try tonight. I'll keep you posted!

Answer (score 0):

A [small article on extras for Aptana](https://breithbarbot.name/blog/astuces-et-plugins-pour-aptana-studio-3) and including the rocker in French by Eclipse.